$\mathrm{Con}(\sf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Con}(\sf{ZFC}+\neg \exists \alpha(\text{$\alpha$ is strongly inaccessible}))$
On page 133 in Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", we are given the following (paraphrasing),

If $\kappa$ is the first strong inaccessible, then $H(\kappa)$ is a model for $\sf{ZFC}$ plus the non-existence of strong inaccessibles.


Corollary: $\mathrm{Con}(\sf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Con}(\sf{ZFC}+\neg \exists \alpha(\text{$\alpha$ is strongly inaccessible}))$

Then we are given the following proof,

Let $\mathrm{Si}(\kappa)$ denote "$\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible". Formally, working in $\sf{ZFC}$, one cannot prove that $\exists \kappa \text{Si}(\kappa)$ (by this corollary), and so one cannot define the least such $\kappa$. Instead, we define $$\mathbf{M} = \{x : \forall \kappa(\mathrm{Si}(\kappa) \rightarrow x \in H(\kappa))\}.$$ So, in $\sf{ZFC}$, one cannot decide whether $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{V}$ or $\mathbf{M}$ is $H(\kappa)$ for the least strongly inaccessible $\kappa$, but in either case, $\mathbf{M}$ satisfies $\sf{ZFC}+\neg \exists \alpha \text{Si}(\alpha)$.

Now, why is he referring to the corollary in the proof? Is that a general comment on the proof-strategy? Obviously he can't use a property of the corollary in the proof of the corollary. Or what is Kunen actually aiming to prove here? I assume he is trying to prove the corollary in bold above?
My understanding of the proof is the following: If $\neg \exists \alpha \mathrm{Si}(\alpha)$ then $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{V}$, trivially. If however there exists a strong inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, then $\mathbf{M}$ would have to be $H(\kappa)$ (I think I agree with these statements). We know from earlier results (e.g. theorem 6.6 in chapter IV of Kunen) that then $H(\kappa)$ is a model for $\sf{ZFC}$. Furthermore, we know that $H(\kappa) = V_{\kappa}$, which are precisely all sets of $\text{rank} < \kappa$ (assuming $\sf{ZFC}$), so $\kappa \not \in V_{\kappa}$, but since $\kappa$ was the least strongly inaccessible cardinal, there can be no such $\kappa$ inside $V_{\kappa}$. Since the statement "$\alpha$ is strongly inaccessible" is absolute, it follows that there is no strong inaccessible cardinal holds in $\mathbf{V}$. So in either case $\mathbf{M}$ is a model for $\sf{ZFC}+\neg \exists \alpha \mathbf{Si}(\alpha)$?
Is the above analysis correct? Am I missing something crucial? I feel like I don't really understand why "$\sf{ZFC}$ can't decide whether $\mathbf{M}$ is $\mathbf{V}$ or $H(\kappa)$ for the least strongly inaccessible cardinal"; I don't even understand what it would mean that $\sf{ZFC}$ could decide what $\mathbf{M}$ is? 

The sentence beginning "Formally ..." is not part of the proof but rather a comment on why the proof involves a seemingly inefficient definition. What Kunen has in mind is the following invalid proof:

Let $\kappa$ be the least inaccessible, and let $M=V_\kappa$.

The reason this is invalid is that we have no guarantee that "the least inaccessible" (or indeed any inaccessible) actually exists in $V$. We could repair this via a proof by contradiction (note that from now on I'm phrasing my arguments slightly differently than Kunen, by explicitly talking about arbitrary models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ at the outset):

Suppose $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$. Then letting $A\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, we know $A\models\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$. Letting $\kappa$ be the least inaccessible in the sense of $A$, we get $(V_\kappa)^A\models\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$, a contradiction.

But in this argument a proof by contradiction is truly unnecessary (and I say that as a huge fan of reductio). A direct approach would be:

Let $A\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ be arbitrary. Let $B=A$ if $A\models\neg\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$, and if $A\models\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$ let $B=(V_\kappa)^A$ where $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible in the sense of $A$. Either way we get $B\models\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$.

This is perfectly valid, but breaking into cases may still feel a bit odd. Kunen's approach has a "uniformity" to it which one may prefer:

Let $A\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ be arbitrary, and let $B$ be the (possibly not proper) substructure of $A$ with underlying set $\{a\in A: A\models\forall x(\mathrm{Si}(x)\rightarrow a\in V_x)\}$. Then $B\models\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\exists x\mathrm{Si}(x)$.


Hm, so in your next to last proof, by $(V_{\kappa})^{A}$ you mean the relativization of $V_{\kappa}$ to the class $A$, where $A$ is an arbitrary model of $\sf{ZFC}$? So by $(V_{\kappa})^{A}$ you mean ${x \in V_{\kappa}: A(x)}$ since a class is really a formula (atleast according to kunen). So for example if $A = V$ then the formula is $x = x$ so then $(V_{\kappa})^{V} = V_{\kappa}$?

@Ben123 It sounds like you're assuming that my $A$ is a subclass of the true universe $V$. It need not be! For example, maybe my $A$ is a non-$\omega$-model (e.g. if $A\models\neg Con(ZFC)$). $A$ here is any model whatsoever of ZFC. But yes, if $A=V$ (ignoring the issue of whether $V$ itself counts as a model, since models should be sets) then $(V_\kappa)^V=V_\kappa$.

Thanks for clarifying; I don't know what non-$\omega$-model is. Also, I was completely unaware that a model needs to be a set. I have gotten no indication from Kunen that a model needs to be a set. Generally he seem to talk about models as some transitive class $\mathbf{M}$ that satisfies some axioms.

I suppose what still what confuses me then, is, what then do you actually mean by $V_{\kappa}^{A}$; which elements will be in this set?

@Ben123 Take the usual formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which intuitively says "$x$ is an ordinal and $y$ is the $x$th layer of the cumulative hierarchy." Note that ZFC proves "For all $x$, if $x$ is an ordinal then there is exactly one $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$." If $A$ is any model of ZFC, and $\kappa$ is an object in $A$ which $A$ thinks is an ordinal, then - since $A$ satisfies ZFC - there is a unique $b\in A$ such that $A\models \varphi(\kappa,b)$. Basically, any definition can be "implemented" in any model of ZFC.

Ops, I also misspoke earlier; Kunen says that $\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{M}} = {x \in \mathbf{M} : A(x)^{\mathbf{M}}}$, but this is when both $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are classes. Alright, I still feel like I don't understand why, when $B = (V_{\kappa})^{A}$, we have that $B \models \neg \exists \alpha \mathrm{Si}(\alpha)$, atleast in your formulation.

Oh, wait, okay, so, hmm, your $\phi(\kappa,b)$ is basically $(V_{\kappa})^{A}$? And it will hold in this $(V_{\kappa})^{A}$ that there is no inaccessible cardinal inside $(V_{\kappa})^{A}$? I.e. can we treat/think about this relativization as $V_{\kappa} \subset V$ (from which it is clear that since $\text{rank} < \kappa$ for all elements in $V_{\kappa}$, and $\kappa$ is the least in. cardinal, there is no in. cardinal in $V_{\kappa}$)? This is the part of your argument which I fail to understand.

You don't need contradiction here. Take a model of ZFC, if it has an inaccessible cardinal, it has a least such cardinal. Cutting that model at that stage will be a model of ZFC without an inaccessible.

I don’t think my last comment said anything about a contradiction @AsafKaragila. Although I am not sure who you answered. I was mainly trying to understand how to think about $(V_{\kappa})^{A}$.
Correction: should be $\varphi(\kappa,b)$ in my earlier comment.

@Ben123: That was a comment to Noah, who said in his answer, that the way to "fix" Kunen's argument is by contradiction.

@AsafKaragila Note what follows: "But in this argument a proof by contradiction is truly unnecessary."
